# Co-authoring in Sharepoint 2016 on-premises without Online Office Server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, co-authoring, oos

Is co-authoring available with desktop app MS Word 2013 in Sharepoint 2016 on-premises without any Office Online Server?
I have a single Sharepoint 2016 server, checked out is turned off in the versioning setting of the libraries. But only one user can edit  the documents at the same time, others get read-only copies. And no co-authoring at all.
Do I need to install Office Online Server just to enable co-authoring? Or I need just to do some additional configurations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work out-of-the-box but i think you have to use Internet Explorer and you have to open the documents via the "..." > EDIT buttons in the document library.

Comment: It does not work. I tried in IE, Chrome, EDIT button in the library - the same result.

Comment: Check if both users can individually save directly to SharePoint. If so, its likely a security issue. Try disabling the firewall, set your SP server as a trusted site in IE. I had the same issue and i found several possible causes while googling... I hope that a conclusive answer will be given since  there is not much information about this feature.. In the meantime see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshoot-co-authoring-in-office-bd481512-3f3a-4b6d-b7eb-ebf9d3626ae7

Comment: Thank You Helb, I read the post you sent and that was the problem - the word doc contained ActiveX controls. I removed them and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without OOS, but you have to make sure following things.

- Document Store in SharePoint.
- You have supported file format ( Co-authoring is only supported on modern file formats including: .docx (Word), .pptx (PowerPoint), and .xlsx (Excel).)
- All users having the latest Office clients.
- All co-authors must have permission to access and edit the documents.

Read more here: [Document collaboration and co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-EE1509B4-1F6E-401E-B04A-782D26F564A4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc254365471)

I think to co-author in the browser you need the Office online server but in office client you are ok.

Answer (score 2):

The Excel client application does not support co-authoring workbooks in SharePoint Server or SharePoint Online.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that all the word docs I wanted to co-author in sharepoint 2016 contained ActiveX controls. After removing these objects from the docs co-authoring worked fine. There was no need to install Office Online Server.

Here is a post about that: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshoot-co-authoring-in-office-bd481512-3f3a-4b6d-b7eb-ebf9d3626ae7

Thank You!